# Passing the elements of an array as argument list to a function (not as a combined string)

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, arguments

I have a customized (console.)log function

```
function clog(toConsole, toFile){
    console.log(toConsole);
    // other things
}
```

But now I can't pass it the string in `'value: %d', value` format

...unless I wrap it in an array

```
clog(['to console: %d', value], 'other things'])
```

Is there a way to pass the elements of the array `['to console: %d', value]` to a function like: `console.log('to console: %d', value)`

Comment: Are you looking for this?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

e.g.
`yourFunction.apply(this || window, yourArrayOfArguments);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).
It allows you to call a function with an array, which is filled in as the arguments.
In this case

```
console.log.apply(console, ['to console: %d', value]);
```

will be equivalent to

```
console.log('to console: %d', value);
```